# defaulting iPhone numeric keypad

Tags: iphone, keyboard

Hi can anybody tell me how to show a default numeric keypad on iPhone rather than a character keypad.

Answer (score 11):

```
[myTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
```

Comment: Iirc, you can also do it in IB